# Runaway pointer causing mayhem in assignment

Tags: c++

I am new here and am not sure if this is the right place to post but I'm in a bit of a time crunch...

I'm taking an intro C++ course and have an assignment that I am well into and I keep getting this error that I cannot troubleshoot. I asked my supplemental instructor and other students and they think it is a runaway pointer. I think I've isolated the problem to a little bit of code but the behavior is odd. The assignment calls to read from two files using a student class, and output. Right now I'm trying to fix this error, especially since it's due tomorrow (Been working on this program for 2 weeks). The code is here:

https://github.com/MetroMayhem/Project1

When I comment out this section I don't get an error:

```
istream & operator>>(istream & in, Student & s)
{
    in >> s.SID;
    in >> s.firstName;
    in >> s.lastName;
    in >> s.courseCount;
    //"""this part: v"""
    //for (int i = 0; i < s.courseCount; i++)
    //  in >> s.courses[i];

    return in;
}
```

But when I don't comment it out and just create one student object in my main, read info into it, and output it, it does just fine. But when I try to loop reading it in, I get some crazy wacko error with an 'xutility' file opening and saying I'm accessing invalid memory.

This does not work in my main():

```
while (studentInput.good()) {
    studentInput >> students[studentIndex++];
}
```

But this works:

```
studentInput >> students[0];
studentOutput << students[0];
```

I'm just all sorts of confused and any tips would be nice.

Edit: Sorry for asking this question, as it is too vague. I will keep trying to fix it and let you know if I find what's wrong.

Edit2: Thanks for your input I was able to get all my errors gone and get my program running thanks to your tips.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve]. Nobody here is going to download a project and debug it.  Sorry.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry. It was worth a try, I just don't know what to do since I've been "debugging" for days and trying to use all my resources...

Comment: How would I go about getting help for my code? Or do I just need to start from scratch and see if I can find what I did wrong?

Comment: It might be time to start using **valgrind**

Comment: Include relevant parts of your code in your question, not in a link.  Since the problem seems to be with the `students` array, include the declaration and initialization of that variable.

Comment: Okay I'll do that next time. Apparently I was wrong in where my error was. I just didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to allocate memory to `s.courses`:

```
s.courses.resize(s.courseCount);
```

Besides, you probably forgot to allocate memory to `students`.  You should do either of the following:

```
students.resize(numberOfStudents); // it should not be more than numberOfStudents students
while (studentInput.good()) {
    studentInput >> students[studentIndex++];
}
```

or:

```
while (studentInput.good()) {
    studentInput >> student;
    students.push_back(student);
}
```

or:

```
while (studentInput.good()) {
    students.resize(studentIndex);
    studentInput >> students[studentIndex++];
}
```

Comment: This is a good point, thank you. Sorry I've never used dynamic arrays before so I'm still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `operator>>()`, your code modifies `s.courses[i]`.   You have provided no information about what `courses` is.

It is presumably - although you have not said so - a pointer, an array, or a `std::vector<Something>`.  In all those cases, the size needs to be no less than `s.courseCount`, but your code does nothing to ensure that.      If the size is not enough, the code will exhibit undefined behaviour (a common, but not guaranteed, symptom is a program crash).

Similarly, the loop

```
while (studentInput.good()) {
    studentInput >> students[studentIndex++];
}
```

needs to ensure `students` holds the required number of elements.  Otherwise the result is also undefined behaviour.

The thing to realise is that arrays and standard containers (like `std::vector`) do not magically resize themselves on accessing their elements  (e.g. `studentInput >> students[studentIndex++]` does not magically ensure that `students` contains more than `studentIndex` elements).

You haven't actually specified what `Student::courses` (the member named `courses` in the type `Student`) is, or what (in later code) `students` is.  So it is not possible to give advice on how to resize them.     What they are (e.g. an array, a pointer, a `std::vector`) will determine how (or even if) they can be resized.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, this is my first time using all these things. Courses is a structure, which is used to make "course objects" to store in a dynamic array within the Student class... I tried making a resize function but I don't think it works.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in your resizeArray. It works fine as long as studentIndex < ARRAY_SIZE.

If resizeArray is not a requirement, I would personally scrap it and just get the file size directly, and then create a students array from that size. I did this to get it to work fully:

```
//move file cursor to end
studentInput.seekg(0, studentInput.end);

//get file length
int ARRAY_SIZE = studentInput.tellg();

//return cursor to beginning of file
studentInput.seekg(0, studentInput.beg);

int studentIndex = 0;
Student *students = new Student[ARRAY_SIZE];

//short circuit array size, and keep reading until EOF/bad
while ((studentIndex < ARRAY_SIZE) && (studentInput >> students[studentIndex++])) {
}
```

Comment: Wow that's nifty. I haven't learned about those methods yet but I'll look into that. Thanks.